# Autocomplete won't show a value and let me set a new one

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui, react-hook-form

I'm using material UI Autocomplete and react-hook-form to build a modal, but I simply can't show a value and change it at the same time.
When I pass the “default” value to `InputValue`, it does show up on the screen, but I can't edit it via input, and when I place it down on `value` it won't show on the screen, but it does let me change values via input and select.

This would be my component that is being rendered

```
<Autocomplete
      id={name}
      options={options}
      getOptionLabel={(option) => (option.descricao ? option.descricao : "")}
      filterOptions={filterOptions}
      onChange={(e, options) =>
        // console.log(options)
        setValue(name, options?.descricao)
      }
      // onInputChange={(e, v) => setValue(name, v)}
      value={cnae ? cnae : ""}
      inputValue={cnae ? cnae : ""}
      renderOption={(props, options) => (
        <Box component="li" {...props}>
          {options.id +
            "/" +
            options.grupo.divisao.id +
            ", " +
            options.descricao}
        </Box>
      )}
      loading={loading}
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField
          {...params}
          {...other}
          label={label}
          error={Boolean(errors[name])}
          helperText={errors[name] ? errors[name].message : ""}
        />
      )}
    />
```

This are the what props are being passed:

```
<ACCnae
                    name="cnae"
                    label="Ramo"
                    fullWidth
                    errors={errors}
                    options={context.cnae}
                    setValue={setValue}
                    cnae={getValues("cnae")}
                    required
                  />
```

And as you can tell here, i'm typing, but only clearing and selecting works
[image: gif]

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way to make it work, but it's definitely not the right way or the best way to do it.
First I find the whole object that I need to set as the value on the autocomplete, that's the only way to actually make it work.
And if the object is already set I use the setValue from react-hook-form to set the new value to the data object.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    if (!obj) {
      setObj(options.find((item) => item.descricao === cnae));
    }
    if (obj?.descricao) {
      setValue(name, obj.descricao);
    }
  }, [cnae, obj]);
```

And the only thing that I've changed from the previous component is that now onChange actually takes setObj

```
<Autocomplete
      id={name}
      options={options}
      getOptionLabel={(option) => option?.descricao}
      filterOptions={filterOptions}
      onChange={(e, options) => setObj(options)}
      value={obj ? obj : ""}
      renderOption={(props, options) => (
        <Box component="li" {...props}>
          {options.id +
            "/" +
            options.grupo.divisao.id +
            ", " +
            options.descricao}
        </Box>
      )}
      loading={loading}
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField
          {...params}
          {...other}
          label={label}
          error={Boolean(errors[name])}
          helperText={errors[name] ? errors[name].message : ""}
        />
      )}
    />
```

If anyone finds a better or simpler way to do it pls let me know